# Object used in Twitter WindowsPhone App

Tags: c#, xaml, twitter, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am looking for the name the graphic object that twitter app uses to display tweets in a twitter feed.

Let me be more precise , when you see your HomeTimeline for example , tweets are displayed in a rectangle and when you touch lightly this rectangle, it moves slightly.

I would like to know what is the name of that rectangle.

Thank you very much !

Comment: An image explaining what you're looking would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I guess I know what you mean. This behaviour is called TiltEffect!

Try to add this to your App.xaml.cs

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Phone.Controls.TiltEffect.SetIsTiltEnabled(RootFrame, true);
}

private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Phone.Controls.TiltEffect.SetIsTiltEnabled(RootFrame, true);
}
```

Now all objects that are touchable in any kind of Lists or Listboxes should react on your touch gestures.

Is that what you needed?

Comment: Hi thank you this is the desired effect but i added those line of codes and nothing changed.

Comment: Can you show us some code of the object that needs to have this effect and where it is embedded in?

Comment: Thank you i have found the solution and used a slightly different way !